# Find continuity of elements in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

how can i find the continuity of a field and starting position
The input is like

```
A-1
B-2
B-3
B-4
C-5
C-6
```

The output i want is

```
A,1,1
B,3,2
C,2,5
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain why that's the output and show your attempts

Comment: that is for counting bounce rates for a website page from its weblogs..
O you could just tell me about finding bounce rate for a website.

Comment: My primary question is how are `B 2` and `C 2` made? Where is `C-6` or `B-4` going?

Comment: Input is-
**value,index**
Output is like
**value,countinuous_counts,startindex**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you do not have discontinuous data with respect to a `value`, you can get the desired results by first grouping on `value` and using `COUNT` and `MIN` to get `continuous_counts` and `start_index` respectively.

```
A = LOAD 'data' USING PigStorage('-') AS (value:chararray;index:int);

B = FOREACH (GROUP A BY value) GENERATE
    group as value,
    COUNT(A) as continuous_counts,
    MIN(A.value) as start_index;

STORE B INTO 'output' USING PigStorage(',');
```

If your data does have the possibility of discontinuous data, the solution is not longer trivial in native pig and you might need to write a UDF for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Group and count the number of values for continous_counts. i.e.

```
A,1
B,3
C,2
```

Get the top row for each value. i.e.

```
A,1
B,2
C,5
```

Join the above two relations and get the desired output.

```
A = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage('-') AS (value:chararray;index:int);
B = GROUP A BY value;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE group as value,COUNT(A.value) as continuous_counts;
D = FOREACH B {
    ordered = ORDER B BY index;
    first = LIMIT ordered 1;
    GENERATE first.value,first.index;
    }
E = JOIN C BY value,D BY value;
F = FOREACH E GENERATE C::value,C::continuous_counts,D::index;
DUMP F;
```